# Apache 301 redirect adding port when using relative URL

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Using Apache RewriteRule, I'm trying to do the following:

```
RewriteRule ^/foo /somedirectory/foo [NC,L,R=301]
```

The problem is that when it redirects, it is going to the following URL:

```
http://www.foo.com:81/somedirectory/foo
```

Is there a way to prevent the port from being written. I'm using a relative URL mainly because we have two sites (.com and .ca) that are on the same machines. I would normally do it like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/foo http://www.foo.com/somedirectory/foo [NC,L,R=301]
```

but if I am going to `http://www.foo.ca/foo` then it will redirect to the .com site.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Just need to do this:

```
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" "\.ca"
RewriteRule ^/foo http://www.foo.ca/somedirectory/foo [NC,L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^/foo http://www.foo.com/somedirectory/foo [NC,L,R=301]
```

Just had to do the RewriteCond with the correct regex to check for the .ca.